# I need this squares to 'fall' or be positioned lower when there's nothing under them

Tags: python

So for an assignment I'm doing we've made 4 different 'blocks' or square drawings using turtle and we have to make it so that when a parameter in a given list of arrangements is 'X' the block is missing and it doesn't draw it. I've done this part already. But from that, if the block is drawn in the 'air' it needs to be moved so that it draws on the 'floor' (see link below). 
http://prntscr.com/ewokpc
[image]

```
arrangement_81 = [['Block B', 'Bottom right', 'Right', 'X'],
              ['Block D', 'Bottom left', 'Right', 'X'],
              ['Block A', 'Top right', 'Right', 'O'],
              ['Block C', 'Top left', 'Right', 'O']]
```

The above arrangement is for the picture shown. I basically need the two blocks pictured to be drawn in the bottom 2 squares.

Comment: It's a print screen link.

Comment: I see someone added it now. When I went to the link before, it was just a blank screen.

Comment: Ahh ok. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like whatever command places the blocks at `y=500, 250` change it to `y=250, 0`

Comment: no because it needs to account for arrangements that want to place it normally as well. If that makes sense?

Comment: sure it makes sense, but it's possibly difficult or unlikely anyone to suggest a solution without being able to reproduce the problem